# is OCS (openshift container storage) supported in openshift OKD 4

Tags: openshift, okd

I have OKD 4.5 installed on bare metal servers. I am looking for options to configure storage in worker node itself. In OKD 3.11 I was using Glusterfs as distributed storage and It seems glusterfs is not supported in OKD4. As alternate I am thinking to use OCS openshift container storage, But I could not find this operator in the OKD4 operatorHub.

Is there anyway to use glusterfs as PV or install OCS in OKD4 ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes OCS is available on OCP v4.x, it is based on Ceph instead of Gluster

The official links to the doc:

- https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_openshift_container_storage/4.5/
- https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.6/storage/persistent_storage/persistent-storage-ocs.html

Answer (score 0):

The original question was "Is there anyway to use glusterfs as PV or install OCS in OKD4 ?"

I don't think that OCS can be installed in OKD (It can, of course, be installed in OCP).  I would love to be wrong, though. Not having an open-distribution of OCS means that even test and dev environments need to run costly licensed versions of OCP if you want to use OCS at all.  It's a drag.

I suppose you could install the Rook operator to deploy and manage Ceph... it should be more-or-less the same thing, but it is not supported by Red Hat in production environments, so likely won't fit the bill for many shops.

GlusterFS appears to have no future in Red Hat as a container storage solution.